# communicate to serial port

Tags: visual-c++, serial-port, serial-communication, createfile

I am trying to communicate to the serial port which is "COM4" in visual studio 2012.

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void system_error(char *name) {
// Retrieve, format, and print out a message from the last error.  The 
// `name' that's passed should be in the form of a present tense noun 
// (phrase) such as "opening file".
//
    char *ptr = NULL;
    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
        0,
        GetLastError(),
        0,
        (char *)&ptr,
        1024,
        NULL);

    fprintf(stderr, "\nError %s: %s\n", name, ptr);
    LocalFree(ptr);
}

void main()
{
    HANDLE serialHandle;


serialHandle = CreateFile("\\\\.\\COM4", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);


// Do some basic settings
DCB serialParams = { 0 };
serialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(serialParams);


if (!GetCommState(serialHandle, &serialParams))
    system_error("Get COM State.");
serialParams.BaudRate = CBR_115200;
serialParams.ByteSize = DATABITS_8;
serialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
serialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;

if (!SetCommState(serialHandle, &serialParams))
    system_error("Set COM State.");

// Set timeouts

// set short timeouts on the comm port.
COMMTIMEOUTS timeout = { 0 };
timeout.ReadIntervalTimeout = 1;
timeout.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;
timeout.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 1;
timeout.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;
timeout.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 1;
if (!SetCommTimeouts(serialHandle, &timeout))
    system_error("setting port time-outs.");

DWORD dwBytesWritten;
char data = 165;

if ( !WriteFile(serialHandle, &data, (DWORD) sizeof(data), &dwBytesWritten, NULL))
        system_error("writing data to port");

    if (dwBytesWritten != sizeof(data))
        system_error("not all data written to port");
data = 00;
int isWritten = WriteFile(serialHandle, &data, (DWORD) sizeof(data), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
data = 165;
isWritten = WriteFile(serialHandle, &data, (DWORD) sizeof(data), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

CloseHandle(serialHandle);
}
```

I am trying this code and getting errors in all lines that i checked for error using `system_error` function. The `serialHandle` is always "0xffff" which is INVALID_HANDLE. I also tried turning the UINICOCE characters off.

any suggestion?

Comment: You use system_error() everywhere, expect where it matters most.  After the CreateFile() call when it returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.  If it fails then everything will fail, no point in continuing.  Fix your code so you know why it failed.  And never hard-code a port name, it won't be the same on another machine or two years from now.

Comment: yes, you are right. the error is because of 'createfile()'. how can i fix this? @HansPassant

Comment: Try using `0` in place of `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL`, as it says on MSDN [in this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363201.aspx).

Comment: Please check your comport is valid.